# How to uninstall compiled GTK+

Tags: gtk3, uninstall

A few days ago I compiled GTK+ 3.12 on my Ubuntu 14.04 and Linux Mint 17 (with Cinnamon) distros. It messed up the appearance. How can I remove it totally and safely? I didn't change the default installation location when compiling.

I also have versions 3.10 and 2.24 (installed by default.)

Comment: Have a look at this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139181/installing-from-source-do-i-need-to-keep-the-extracted-tarball-directory/139183#139183

Comment: @goldilocks I got this error: `make: *** No rule to make target 'uninstall'. Stop.`

Comment: If you are using a fresh extraction of the tarball you will have to run `./configure` again first.  This is the case if running just plain `make` returns  `make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.`

Comment: How did you installed it?

Comment: @goldilocks Thank you! I already tried both `./configure` and `make` and then tried `make uninstall` and that worked. I also think that installing the program using `checkinstall` and then uninstalling it using synaptic or apt-get or any package manager would be suitable, right?

Comment: @goldilocks Can you please make your comment a post (and maybe have a point to `checkinstall`), so that I can mark it as the answer? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source packages which use [autotools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_build_system) -- `./configure; make; make install` -- usually have a `make uninstall` target as well.  However, that target doesn't exist until you run `./configure` (because there's actually no makefile), so if you get the error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'uninstall'. Stop.
```

That is likely the problem.  This can be confirmed by trying just `make`; if you get `make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.` then there is no makefile because `./configure` has not been successfully run.

If you are using a fresh extraction of the source package to do the uninstall, it probably is not incredibly important if your options to `./configure` are not exactly the same as the original build (with the exception of the target directories, which obviously must be the same) but it would be good to try and get close if you can remember them.

> I also think that installing the program using checkinstall and then uninstalling it using synaptic or apt-get or any package manager would be suitable, right?

I haven't used [checkinstall](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckInstall) myself, but it certainly looks like a good idea and does appear to be explicitly useful in uninstalling things if you have used it in the first place.  As far as I can tell it is only current for debian derived distros (such as ubuntu).